# How can execute a sequence in JpaRepository?

Tags: java, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

how can execute a sequence in JpaRepository?

and then read the id from the Entity.

```
    public interface EmailRepository extends JpaRepository<Email, Long> {

    }

    emailService.persistEmail(from, to, subject, content);
        @Inject
        private EmailRepository emailRepository;

        @Transactional
        public void persistEmail(String mailFrom, String mailTo, String subject, String content) {
            Email email = new Email(mailFrom, mailTo, content, subject);
            Email persisted = emailRepository.save(email);
            persisted.getId();
            log.debug("Persisted Information for Mail: {}", persisted.getMailFrom());
        }

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode(of = "id")
@Table(name = "mails")
public class Email {

    @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @Column(name = "mail_from", nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String mailFrom;

    @Column(name = "mail_to", nullable = false, length = 250)
    private String mailTo;

    @Column(name = "mail_subject", nullable = false, length = 200)
    private String subject;

    @Column(name = "mail_content", nullable = false, length = 5000)
    private String content;

    public Email(String mailFrom, String mailTo, String subject, String content) {
        this.mailFrom = mailFrom;
        this.mailTo = mailTo;
        this.subject = subject;
        this.content = content;
    }
}
```

i can't persist because the id is null. Any ideas. Also how can i ignore create a constructor in lambook without id

Comment: What does the entity class `Email` look like? Does it have a `Long id` field? Does that field have an `@Id` and `@GeneratedValue` annotation?

Comment: can you attach the code of the `Email` class?

Comment: i mean to lambook to create a constructor  for all arguments, but not for the id

Comment: Your RDBMS supports autoincrement/serial columns? That is what `IDENTITY` is using, but you dont say which RDBMS

Comment: I'm using postgre

Comment: and the table was created with what DDL? Did you let the JPA provider create it? And `IDENTITY` is not a "Sequence" (title of the question), it is an autoincrement field. I'd expect you to have type "SERIAL" for the "ID" column

Comment: The idea is jparepository to create the id sequence which I should get from the entity and use it to create a something like uid from this id, encode it and use for insert in mail_from like part of the mail 1234&%$%@domain.com. And idea is to persist in one transaction.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing a label for the Id. Have you try using the @TableGenerator label like the following?

```
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="EMAIL_SEQ")
@TableGenerator(name="EMAIL_SEQ", table="SequenceKey", pkColumnName="SeqKey", pkColumnValue="EmailBean", valueColumnName="Seq" )
private Long id;
```

Comment: I have tried your example, but no success, any other ideas

Comment: Sorry, you should change the @Generatedvalue label also, I corrected the answer.

Comment: '  @Id
    @Column(name = "id")
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.TABLE, generator="MAILS_SEQ")
    @TableGenerator(name="MAILS_SEQ", table="mails", pkColumnName="id", pkColumnValue="id" )
    private Long id; ' is it correct? seems like it is not working

Comment: Maybe if can give more info about your aplication context...are you using spring? Still I don&#39;t think you should change the pkColumnName or pkColumnValue. I use the same pattern for all my domain classes.

Comment: CREATE TABLE public.mails
(
  id integer NOT NULL,
  mail_from character varying(250) NOT NULL,
  mail_to character varying(250) NOT NULL,
  mail_subject character varying(200) NOT NULL,
  mail_content character varying(5000) NOT NULL,
  sent_date timestamp(6) without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT pk_mails PRIMARY KEY (id)

Comment: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: invalid input syntax for integer: "id"
  Position: 40

Answer (score 0):

See here

[How to set auto increment primary key in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7718585/how-to-set-auto-increment-primary-key-in-postgresql)

and here

[JPA and PostgreSQL with GenerationType.IDENTITY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497768/jpa-and-postgresql-with-generationtype-identity)

If you want to use  `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` then your ID column needs to be of type `SERIAL` and not `integer` as it currently is.