# Null in foreign key hibernate @OneToMany while saving

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I have two tables in database like `order_header_snapshot` and `index_header_snapshot`. `OrderHeaderSnapshot` can have a list of `IndexHeader`. `IndexHeader` has column `order_header_snapshot_id` as a foreign key. I don't describe others fields because it is not important.

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class OrderHeaderSnapshot {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_header_snapshot_id")
    private List<IndexHeaderSnapshot> indexHeaderSnapshot = new ArrayList<>();
```

```java
@Entity
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
class IndexHeaderSnapshot {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
}
```

At the end while saving in repository I catch an exception

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "order_header_snapshot_id" of relation "index_header_snapshot" violates not-null constraint
```

I don't have an idea what I do wrong. Please help :)

Answer (score 0):

As soon as in your `IndexHeaderSnapshot` you have id column annotated with `@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)` it looks like you are adding detached instances of `IndexHeaderSnapshot` into `OrderHeaderSnapshot.indexHeaderSnapshot`. The entities must be attached to Hibernate session, i.e. call `IndexHeaderRepository.save(listOfIndexHeaderSnapshots)` before adding them into `OrderHeaderSnapshot.indexHeaderSnapshot`. Hibernate will request ids for them from the database and attach them to current session.

Also make sure that your table in PostgreSQL described as

```sql
CREATE TABLE index_header_snapshot (
    id INT GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY,
    ...
);
```

See https://stackoverflow.com/a/66421047/12473843

Comment: Table I had created id in table like you recommended. 

But If I understand correctly I have to save OrderHeader firstly and next save other entities?

Comment: I think you are missing `ALWAYS` keyword. Also make sure that you add attached entitties to `OrderHeaderSnapshot.indexHeaderSnapshot`

Comment: I guess it's not true that these entities are detached. In another part of system we have implemented solution like above. We save whole entity with children without problem using one repository

Comment: Well, you can just try calling `IndexHeaderRepository.save(listOfIndexHeaderSnapshots)` before adding them into the list. I'm sure this will solve your issue, but make sure your are doing it within the same transaction with `OrderHeaderSnapshotRepository.save()`

Comment: @Soft the only reason why you see nulls in id field is that the entities are detached for an attached one cannot have null as id

Comment: Although I can't save index_header without order_header id because field marked as foreign key will be null while saving. Field is nullable false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255438/discussion-between-sergey-tsypanov-and-soft).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, i have answer

I've replaced

```
@JoinColumn(name = "order_header_snapshot_id")
```

with

```
@JoinColumn(name = "order_header_snapshot_id", nullable = false)
```

and it works :)