# JPA With postgresql

Tags: postgresql, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

When i create table Entity in Jpa With hibernate using PostgreSQL database like,

```
tire - 

 @Entity
 @Immutable
  public class User_entity_t implements Serializable, Cloneable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = -7049957706738879274L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long _judId;

@Column(nullable = false)
private String name;
```

i get exception as

```
{syntax error at or near "auto_increment"} Primary Key Id
```

Comment: This may be a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40497768/jpa-and-postgresql-with-generationtype-identity

Comment: Sounds as if your obfuscation layer doesn't know how Postgres handles "auto increment" columns (either as `serial` or as `identity`)

Comment: 1) You should avoid to use AUTO and go for IDENTITY. 2) auto_increment sounds like MySQL do you have the correct dialect set?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli Thanks For reply. but when iuse Id
 GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
 Column(columnDefinition = "serial")
 private Long id;
 Same error

Comment: and you are sure you have the correct syntax set for Postgres?

Comment: @SimonMartinelli yes now problem is solve.thanks your advice and help.

Answer (score 0):

auto_increment sounds like MySQL

You have to set the correct Hibernate dialect.